# Webdriver - How to scroll page down to element inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, mocha.js

I want to reach to some element (WYIWYG editor) inside an iFrame.

I've tried a lot of alternatives but all of them are not solved my problem. :/

Is anyone of you guys can assist? I think the implementation there is a little bit problematic and probably need some hack or a magical solution to solve this..

**My code:**

```
//node packages
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('chromedriver');
const chai = require('chai');


//conf
let element_time = 10000;

let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(/* ... */)
    .build();

//classes
const actionSequence = webdriver.ActionSequence;
const key = webdriver.Key;
const By = webdriver.By;
const until = webdriver.until;
const expect = chai.expect;


//test cases
describe("Test", async function(){

    this.timeout(30000);

    before(function(){
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    });


    it("Step 1 - Heading to rm.com", async function(){
        await driver.get('https://www.rt.com'); 
    });

    it("Step 2 - Heading into the main article", async function(){
        try {
            await driver.findElement(By.css('a.main-promobox__link')).click();
        } finally {
            return null;
        }       
    });

    it("Step 4 - Switching to iFrame and publishing the content", async function(){
        try {
            await driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.css("div.sppre_frame-container>iframe")));
            let userName = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/input'));
            let txtEditor =  driver.findElement(By.className("ql-editor"));
                await userName.click();
                await userName.sendKeys("Idan");
                await driver.actions(txtEditor).mouseMove().mouseUp().mouseDown().perform();
                await txtEditor.sendKeys('Bla.. Bla.. Bla..' + "\n" + 'Bla.. Bla.. Bla..');
                driver.sleep(2000);

        } finally {
            return null;
        }   
    });


})
```

The specific element I want to reach to -

[image]

**Error:**

```
  Test
    ✓ Step 1 - Heading to rm.com (8159ms)
    ✓ Step 2 - Heading into the main article (10942ms)
(node:43961) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".ql-editor"}
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.186)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540469 (1881fd7f8641508feb5166b7cae561d87723cfa8),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.3 x86_64)
(node:43961) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
    ✓ Step 4 - Switching to iFrame and publishing the content (270ms)
```

**Technical info:**
Node JS | Mocha

Comment: So what line is failing and what's the error?

Comment: No error.. just typing the first input and skipping on the test without any information in the log.

Comment: @lloyd Actually now it's reaching to the iframe but it doesn't scroll down to the relevant elements inside the iframe and doesn't recognize the text editor there (see error and updated code inside the main post)